# Redirect to Different Controller Method (Error in IIS. Works in IIS Express)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

The snippet below should redirect to a different controller method when an error is handled inside the MVC Application_Error routine. This works fine in IIS Express but fails in my test environment in full blown IIS. If incoming request is from Ajax it should redirect to the Shared controller method ErrorDetails, from a separate client side ajax request. How can I tweak the code below to work in both IIS Express and IIS?

```
RequestContext requestContext = ((MvcHandler) httpContext.CurrentHandler).RequestContext;
/* when the request is ajax the system can automatically handle a mistake    with a JSON response. then overwrites the default response */
if (requestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    httpContext.Response.Clear();
    string controllerName = requestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
    IControllerFactory factory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
    IController controller = factory.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
    ControllerContext controllerContext = new ControllerContext(requestContext, (ControllerBase)controller);


    JsonResult jsonResult = new JsonResult();
    jsonResult.Data = new { result = "Failure", message = Properties.Resources.WebCoreException };
    jsonResult.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    jsonResult.ExecuteResult(controllerContext);
    httpContext.Response.End();
}
```